# using php mail function with multiple headers is showing /r/n after email is sent

Tags: php, email, header

I am using the php mail function, and i have multiple headers. the problem is when i send them, they display the /r/n in the email information. why is this being displayed?

i have placed the headers into an array, seperated by /r/n. when  the email is sent, it displays r n in the users inbox. what do i need to do so it doesnt display r n?

```
$headers=array(
    'From: xzy@gmail.com',
    'Content-Type:text/html',
    'Reply-To: xyz@gmail.com'
);
mail($email_address,$subject,$body,implode("/r/n",$headers));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `/` instead of `\`. Line breaks are denoted using a backslash, so it should be `\r\n`.

Comment: "Also use " instead of ' in the header array." -> why?

Comment: `\*` are only parsed in strings that are enclosed with `"` not `'`.

Comment: Doesn't matter as he is imploding it.

Comment: @ethanh what `\*`? Did OP edit the question or am I getting blind?

Comment: `*` as in `\ ` anything ex: `\r` or `\n`

Comment: But there is no stuff to parse in the headers array.

Comment: You added `\r\n` using implode, but then it doesn't matter

Comment: @EthanH may you please link some documentation on using `"` and it parsing things in middle. I wanted to read it. So if I did `'` then the `'\n'` would literally be `\n` correct?

Comment: @Noitidart, correct. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Thanks very much sir!

Answer (score 3):

Use "\r\n" not "/r/n". You're using the wrong slash

Answer (score 2):

It should be `"\r\n"`, backslashes are for special characters which cannot be displayed!
Plus they are only parsed in double quoted strings (`"`)